# Duplicate Email notifications on Mercury Pressflow (drupal)

Tags: drupal, notifications, pressflow

We’re running into an issue sending duplicate notifications to our users using the Notifications module on our Mercury Pressflow implementation.  The duplicate messages are identical save one thing- the [node-url] token is being replaced with ‘default’ in one of the messages.  All the other tokens in the message are being replaced correctly.
The duplicate emails do not happen consistently, maybe 10-15% of the notifications sent out, however a duplicate message always has the proper url & the ‘default’ url.

The only major modification we’ve made to Mercury was spinning off MySQL to it’s own server and adding replication.  We currently have the reads set up to round robin between the 2 MySQL instances.

I have done the following troubleshooting based on finding similar issues
made sure the cron job is calling the correct url
replaced all configurations named ‘default’ with the site name (Memcached, Varnish, and Apache configs)
disabled caching in an init_hook in the notifications module

Has anyone out there experienced anything similar with Notifications and Mercury?  Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "Mercury" stack is external to Drupal and doesn't affect how email is queued or sent. Something within your messaging/notifications configuration or use is causing multiple messages to be created.

If you have any custom code here, I would look at that and try to trace the token variance.